# Webpack 5 Dev server not serving CSS

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have setup a simple webpack 5 config file with a dev server that seems to be working but when I add

```
<link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

to the index.html file I get no CSS loading. Currently in dev mode I am choosing to use 'style-loader' over the 'MiniCssExtractPlugin' to enable hot module reloading natively.

any help would be greatly appreciated. There are no errors in the webpack console output just no CSS to call from the HTML file.

**Webpack file:**

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require("css-minimizer-webpack-plugin");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = (env, options) => {
    const mode = options.mode;
    return {
        context: __dirname,
        entry: {
            script: './src/index.bundle.ts',
            style: './src/index.bundle.less',
        },
        output: {
            filename: '[name].js',
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/dist')
        },
        devServer: {
            watchFiles: ['src/**/*.less'],
            static: {
                directory: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
                watch: true,
            },
            compress: true,
            port: 9000,
            hot: true,
        },
        devtool: 'source-map',
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.css', '.less']
        },
        plugins: [
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: '[name].css',
                chunkFilename: '[id].css',
                ignoreOrder: false,
            }),
        ],
        module: {
            rules: [{
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            target: 'browserslist'
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.ts(x)?$/,
                    loader: 'ts-loader',
                    exclude: /node_modules/
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [
                        mode === 'production' ? MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader : 'style-loader',
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'postcss-loader', // Run postcss actions
                            options: {
                                postcssOptions: {
                                    config: path.resolve(__dirname, "postcss.config.js"),
                                }
                            }
                        },
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.less$/,
                    use: [
                      mode === 'production' ? MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader : 'style-loader',
                      'css-loader',
                      'less-loader'
                    ]
                },
            ]
        },
        optimization: {
            minimize: true,
            minimizer: [new TerserPlugin(), new CssMinimizerPlugin()]
        },
        target: 'web',
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you've misconfigured

```js
static: {
  directory: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
```

Your output points to `src/dist` so it looks like it should be this instead

```js
static: {
  directory: path.join(__dirname, 'src/dist'),
```

On a side note, it's an anti-pattern to have compiled files within your source folder. Generally this structure is recommended.

```
[repo_root]/
  dist/
  src/
```